# How do I add a pipe the vertical bar (|) into a yaml file from Python

Tags: python, kubernetes, yaml, pyyaml, configmap

I have a task. I need to write python code to generate a yaml file for kubernetes. So far I have been using pyyaml and it works fine. Here is my generated yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  info: 
    name: hostname.com
    aio-max-nr: 262144
    cpu:
      cpuLogicalCores: 4
    memory:
      memTotal: 33567170560
    net.core.somaxconn: 1024
    ...
```

However, when I try to create this configMap the error is that info expects a string() but not a map. So I explored a bit and it seem the easiest way to resolve this is to add a pipe after info like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  info: | # this will translate everything in data into a string but still keep the format in yaml file for readability
    name: hostname.com
    aio-max-nr: 262144
    cpu:
      cpuLogicalCores: 4
    memory:
      memTotal: 33567170560
    net.core.somaxconn: 1024
    ...
```

This way, my configmap is created successfully. My struggling is I dont know how to add that pipe bar from python code. Here I manually added it, but I want to automate this whole process.

part of the python code I wrote is, pretend data is a dict():

```
content = dict()
content["apiVersion"] = "v1"
content["kind"] = "ConfigMap"
data = {...}
info = {"info": data}
content["data"] = info

# Get all contents ready. Now write into a yaml file
fileName = "out.yaml"
with open(fileName, 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(content, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

I searched online and found a lot of cases, but none of them fits my needs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be aware that `: |` is just a syntatic nicety; the actual data that yaml represents is always the same, so unless you're generating that yaml file for _human_ consumption, kubernetes does not care about the pipe scalar. Also, in your code you have `data = {` but in your resulting yaml you have it as a string. That sounds like a fine reason you are not getting the outcome you are expecting.

Comment: @mdaniel THANKS for replying. One way to resolve this is to convert data={...} into a string like this res = json.dumps(data, indent=2). This way, the yaml file looks ugly and kubernetes does create this configmap successfully, but if I do kubectl describe the configmap in kubernetes, the result looks very different from if I have the bar added instead. Yes, the data are all in configmap in kubernetes, but they present in an ugly way though. LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipe makes the contained values a string. That string is not processed by YAML, even if it contains data with YAML syntax. Consequently, you will need to give a string as value.

Since the string contains data in YAML syntax, you can create the string by processing the contained data with YAML in a previous step. To make PyYAML dump the scalar in literal block style (i.e. with `|`), you need a custom representer:

```py
import yaml, sys
from yaml.resolver import BaseResolver

class AsLiteral(str):
  pass

def represent_literal(dumper, data):
  return dumper.represent_scalar(BaseResolver.DEFAULT_SCALAR_TAG,
      data, style="|")

yaml.add_representer(AsLiteral, represent_literal)

info = {
  "name": "hostname.com",
  "aio-max-nr": 262144,
  "cpu": {
    "cpuLogicalCores": 4
  }
}

info_str = AsLiteral(yaml.dump(info))

data = {
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "ConfigMap",
  "data": {
    "info": info_str
  }
}

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

By putting the rendered YAML data into the type `AsLiteral`, the registered custom representer will be called which will set the desired style to `|`.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why is class AsLiteral(str) a pass? If this class does nothing, then why do we need it though?

Comment: @LividFont The instruction that the value of `info` shall be represented via `represent_literal` is communicated to PyYAML by means of using the `AsLiteral` class. Would it be a `str` like everything else, we wouldn't be able to tell PyYAML to treat it differently.

Comment: How should one implement the similar approach using Java- snakeyamlor Jackson ??

Comment: @thebluemagician SnakeYAML has a interface very similar to PyYAML. Jackson doesn't give you access to SnakeYAML's full capabilities (it uses SnakeYAML under the hood) so there is no reason to use Jackson if you target YAML specifically (and not the other formats Jackson supports).